What is the relationship between long range order and long range entanglement?
I'm wondering whether there's a deep connection between long-range entanglement and long-range order. Here's my understanding of these two concepts.

Entanglement. Short-range entanglement basically means it can be related to a trivial product state by a gLU(generalized local unitary transformation). SPT is an example of SRE states with non-trivial order. Long-range entanglement can be further categorized as GHZ-like entanglement, referring to spontaneously symmetry breaking states and intrinsic topological order states.
Order. A long range order seems to be defined as a non-zero value of $\langle\psi|O(x)O(y)|\psi\rangle$ in the thermodynamic limit. Spontaneous symmetry breaking states have long-range order while SPT states don't. However, string order parameter can still be defined for SPT states, reflecting their non-trivial nature.

It seems that from the examples of SPT states and SSB phases, long-range order and long-range entanglement are essentially the same thing. I'm wondering whether this statement is true or not. Meanwhile, there seems to be other ways to define long-range entanglement, such as the non-vanishing mutual information between two distant points. I'm also wondering how these definitions reconcile with each other.

Related https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2059/are-there-connections-between-long-range-entanglement-and-topological-quantum-co. Your example of a GHZ-state is also addressed there.
Long-range entanglement can occur independently of spontaneous symmetry breaking. The most famous example would be quantum spin liquids which do not spontaneously break a symmetry yet host many exotic features explicitly because of long-range entanglement like fractionalization and anyons (see this review on quantum spin liquids).
